# PostgresSQL Query to Include YTD Totals like SUMIFS?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, window-functions

Thanks in advance for any assistance. Writing queries is definitely my biggest weakness.

I have a query written to get data on transactions for each client on each day:

```
select organization, 
       DATE(txn_date), 
       sum(amount) as totalamount 
from sales_receipt 
where EXTRACT(YEAR from txn_date) > 2017 
group by organization, DATE(txn_date)
```

This yields something like:

```
organization date        totalamount
client1      2018-01-01  1000.00  
client1      2018-01-02  500.00    
client1      2018-01-03  800.00  
client2      2018-01-01  600.00  
client2      2018-01-02  300.00    
client2      2018-01-03  200.00
client1      2019-01-01  800.00
client1      2019-01-02  600.00    
client1      2019-01-03  900.00
client2      2019-01-01  400.00  
client2      2019-01-02  600.00
client2      2019-01-03  800.00
```

I'd like to add an additional column that includes the year to date sum of totalamount for each client if possible, something like:

```
organization date        totalamount ytd 
client1      2018-01-01  1000.00     1000.00  
client1      2018-01-02  500.00      1500.00    
client1      2018-01-03  800.00      2300.00
client2      2018-01-01  600.00      600.00  
client2      2018-01-02  300.00      900.00
client2      2018-01-03  200.00      200.00
client1      2019-01-01  800.00      8000.00  
client1      2019-01-02  600.00      1400.00    
client1      2019-01-03  900.00      2300.00
client2      2019-01-01  400.00      400.00  
client2      2019-01-02  600.00      1000.00
client2      2019-01-03  800.00      1800.00
```

Is there a way to do this in the PostgreSQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
select 
    organization, 
    txn_date::date txn_date, 
    sum(amount) as totalamount,
    sum(sum(amount)) over(partition by organization, extract(year from txn_date) order by date) ytd
from sales_receipt 
where txn_date >= '2018-01-01'::date
group by organization, txn_date::date
```

You don't need an extra level of nesting to use window functions.

Also, you seem to want a separate partition for each organization *and* year.

Finally, you can use a direct predicate against the date column rather than apply a function on it (this makes the query much more efficient, especially if an index is available).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. On the order by I got an error the column "date" does not exist. Should that be txn_date in this case? (the query worked perfectly with txn_date)

Comment: @StevenCarlton: welcome. But there is no `date` column in the `order by`, just `txn::date`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a running total which can be done using a window function, after your existing aggregation:

```
select organization, 
       txn_date, 
       totalamount, 
       sum(totalamount) over (partition by organization order by txn_date) as ytd
from (      
    select organization, 
           DATE(txn_date) as txn_date, 
           sum(amount) as totalamount, 
    from sales_receipt 
    where txn_date >= date '2018-01-01' -- this expression can make use of an index on txn_date
    group by organization, DATE(txn_date)
) t;
```

Comment: Wow, that worked with the exception of having multiple years in the data set so ytd is the running total instead of the true year to date total. Any ideas?

Comment: @StevenCarlton: see GMB's answer. He took care of that. I didn't see that requirement

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help!